# Change Python 3 sys.argv when calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, argv, sys

I have a program `main.py` which uses `sys.argv` to run functions from other modules:

e.g:
`python main.py gui` should run the `main` function in `gui.py`
`python main.py server start` should run the `main` function in `server.py`.

But if the program simply runs `server.main()` in this example, `sys.argv` is `['main.py', 'server', 'start']` when it should be `[something, 'start']`.

Since `server.py` also relies on the correct argv, I need to make sure that the argv used in `server.py` is different from the argv recieved by `main.py`. How can I change these values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sys.argv` can just be replaced:

```
saved_argv = sys.argv
try:
    sys.argv = ['./server.py', 'start']
    server.main()
finally:
    sys.argv = saved_argv
```

That said, the fact that you want to do this (outside of a unit test, where this pattern is actually pretty common) indicates that you might want to work on building a better API for your modules.

For example, perhaps `server.py` can have a `main` function for when it's run as a standalone module, but also another function like `run_server()` which can take its own arguments rather than relying on `sys.argv`.

Comment: Thanks. Given the somewhat shaky nature of this kind of solution, I think I'll find a way to update the API to make it more accessible.